# iPhone screen randomly turns on

Tags: ios, iphone

After installing iOS 10, I found that the screen on my iPhone 6s turned on at seemingly random times, and it slightly annoyed me. I now know that this feature does what it is supposed to (turn the screen on when the phone enters certain positions), but I want to disable it.

Is there a setting can I use to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the new **Raise to Wake** functionality.

It can be disabled by going into **Settings** → **Display & Brightness**. Toggle **Raise to Wake** *Off*.